# hover opacity and click opacity

Tags: jquery

I have some image links that change opacity on rollover with jquery. I want to also change the opacity of the "inactive" images when they are clicked and remove the active class of the previous image. Perhaps some code to demonstrate:

html:

```
<div style="width:940px; text-align:center; padding-bottom:10px;">
    <a href="#" class="nobase" onClick='jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer("play", "adI8ZRzjnlE");'>
        <img class="active"  src="images/video_thumbs/003.jpg" width="300" height="167" alt="La Vie en Couleur">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nobase" onClick='jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer("play", "5L1vrwEvP-c");'>
        <img class="inactive" src="images/video_thumbs/001.jpg" width="300" height="167" alt="A Holiday Video">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nobase" onClick='jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer("play", "ijfgzId6jdI");'>
        <img class="inactive"   src="images/video_thumbs/002.jpg" width="300" height="167" alt="La Vie en Couleur">
    </a>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img.inactive").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                "opacity": "1"
            }, "slow");
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                "opacity": "0.6"
            }, "slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

css:

```
.inactive {opacity:0.6;}
.active {opacity:1.0;}
```

so basically it is doing what I want on rollover, but I want to switch the active class on click as well.

Comment: Why are you using inline JavaScript (i.e. `onClick`) when you have jQuery at your full disposal?  Also, why haven't you tried `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` yet?  http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: i'm using it inline because the video click that it plays is different per each link. so is it any better/possible to do it from within the regular javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do most of it in plain ol CSS

```
selector:hover{}

selector:active{}
```

or you can do this

```
$('elm').bind({'click':action,'hover':action});

function action(e){
 $(e.currentTarget).doSomething();
}
```

Comment: He's already doing that with jQuery and he's asking, _"but I want to switch the active class on click as well"_

Answer (score 0):

for what I understood, you want to change the class.
you can use in both hover functions:

```
element.toggleClass('className')
```

or, you can explicitly remove or include the class that you want:

```
element.removeClass('className')
element.addClass('className')
```

I hope that's what you want.  =]

Comment: Kinda sorta. One of the 3 images starts as active and the other 2 inactive. Also I need to add on click instead of hover. and I need to remove the active class from the original active..